# No USB soundcard found in Ubuntu 16.10

Tags: alsa, usb-drive, soundcard, external-soundcard

I have a usb soundcard Edirol UA-1EX and a computer with dual boot (windows 10 and Ubuntu 16.10) and I can't make the Ubuntu recognize the usb soundcard.

aplay -l

```
    **** Lista de Dispositivos PLAYBACK Hardware ****
placa 0: SB [HDA ATI SB], dispositivo 0: ALC892 Analog [ALC892 Analog]
  Dispositivo secundário: 1/1
  Dispositivo secundário #0: subdevice #0
placa 0: SB [HDA ATI SB], dispositivo 1: ALC892 Digital [ALC892 Digital]
  Dispositivo secundário: 1/1
  Dispositivo secundário #0: subdevice #0
placa 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], dispositivo 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Dispositivo secundário: 1/1
  Dispositivo secundário #0: subdevice #0
placa 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], dispositivo 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Dispositivo secundário: 1/1
  Dispositivo secundário #0: subdevice #0
placa 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], dispositivo 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Dispositivo secundário: 1/1
  Dispositivo secundário #0: subdevice #0
placa 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], dispositivo 9: HDMI 3 [HDMI 3]
  Dispositivo secundário: 1/1
  Dispositivo secundário #0: subdevice #0
```

lspci -v | grep -A7 -i "audio"

```
00:14.2 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SBx00 Azalia (Intel HDA) (rev 40)
    Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd SBx00 Azalia (Intel HDA)
    Flags: bus master, slow devsel, latency 32, IRQ 16
    Memory at fe300000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel

--
01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation Device 0fbc (rev a1)
    Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd Device 36d1
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 32
    Memory at fe080000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
```

My USB is not listed at all! Someone knows what is wrong?

**EDIT:**
I have found the solution here: https://askubuntu.com/a/595178/645228
I move the soundcard from USB 3 to USB 2 and now it works!